# Pycharm throws "Memory Error" despite increasing xmx on a 128G system

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, out-of-memory

I have a SciPy sparse matrix which I would like to convert to dense using

```
a=a.todense()
```

,but Pycharm throws a memory error.

MY `pycharm64.vmoptions` file looks like:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx102400m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

and I'm on a system with 128GB of RAM.

The free command shows that most of the available RAM is not being used while PyCharm is running. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Why do you think this is a PyCharm issue? Are you sure you have enough memory to materialize your sparse matrix? What are the dimensions/data-types?

Comment: What exactly is the error being thrown?

Comment: The error being thrown is "Memory Error". It is a 64 bit python. The sparse matrix is a csr, and I'm trying to convert it to a dense array. It's possible that the dense matrix consumes more than the available RAM, but then I would expect the RAM consumption shown by "top" to spike when the program runs, which it does not.

Comment: Do you encounter the same error when running the code outside PyCharm?